# How to make slick slider with cropped slides

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, slick.js

I need to make slick slider where next slider from right is cropped by half, but not from the left side. I did it with set up  slidesToShow: 1.5, like in the screen below.

[image]

But also I need to make that if it's the last slide, then the previous slide should cropped by half and after the last slide there is not empty space, like in the screen below.
And if I swipe back it should be like in the first screen, cropped by the right side only.

How can I  achieve this? I was looking for examples but didn't find much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add folowing css

```
div.slick-list{
  padding:0 50px 0 0;
}
```